# Add the product attribute term name to body class in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I wish to add a body class depending on an attribute of a product, for example color, so if the product color is red, I wish to add the class 'red' to the body tag.

What hook would I use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a custom function hooked in **`body_class`** filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    if( ! is_product() ) return $classes;

    global $post;
    $custom_classes = array();

    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

    foreach( $product->get_attributes() as $taxonomy => $wc_attribute ){
        if( $taxonomy == 'pa_color' )
            $custom_classes = $wc_attribute->get_slugs();

    return array_merge( $classes, $custom_classes );
} );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.