# How to add Woocommerce Product Attributes term as a body class on the cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Just want to know if there is a way to add the prouct attributes term as a body class?

I have try this post [Add the product attribute term name to body class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244244/add-the-product-attribute-term-name-to-body-class-in-woocommerce), but it didnt work for me.

I am using WooCommerce 5.8.0.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: There is a missing } in the example code. I have tested it and its working :) Just make sure you are checking the right attribute.

Comment: @Ruvee, thank you, will give it a try.